# Как можно добавить 1 див который после каждый 10 запись в php?

Tags: php

Как можно добавить 1 див который после каждый 10 запись в `php`? Например типа реклама и т.д.

```
?php
$query="SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE post_user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY `post_id` DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$post = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($post) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_url = $profile_data['user_url'];
        $user_mini_avatar = $profile_data['user_mini_avatar'];
        $user_first_name = $profile_data['user_first_name'];
        $user_last_name = $profile_data['user_last_name'];
        $post_id = $row['post_id'];
        $post_content = $row['post_content'];
        $post_date = $row['post_date'];
        echo '                   <div class="post" id="post'.$post_id.'">
                                    <div id="post_header">
                                        <div id="author_avatar"><a href="'.$user_url.'"><img src="images/'.$user_mini_avatar.'" /></a></div>
                                        <div id="post_info"><a href="'.$user_url.'">'.$user_first_name.' '.$user_last_name.'</a><div class="delete_post" id="delete_'.$post_id.'" style="float: right; margin: 10px;">x</div><br>'.$post_date.'</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="post_content">
                                        '.$post_content.'
                                    </div>';
        echo '<div id="comments">';
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE comment_user_id = '$user_id' AND comment_post_id = '".$post_id."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $comment_id = $row['comment_id'];
            $comment_content = $row['comment_content'];
            $comment_date = $row['comment_date'];
            echo '                   <div class="comment" id="comment'.$comment_id.'">
                                         <div id="comment_header">
                                             <div id="author_avatar"><a href="'.$user_url.'"><img src="images/'.$user_mini_avatar.'" /></a></div>
                                             <div id="comment_info"><a href="'.$user_url.'">'.$user_first_name.' '.$user_last_name.'</a><div class="delete_comment" id="delete_'.$comment_id.'" style="float: right; margin: 10px;">x</div><br>'.$comment_date.'</div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div id="comment_content">
                                             '.$comment_content.'
                                         </div>
                                         </div>';
            }
        echo '                    </div><div id="add_comment">
                                             <div id="author_avatar"><a href="/"><img src="images/'.$user_data['user_mini_avatar'].'" /></a></div>
                                             <div id="add_comment_content">
                                                 <textarea id="add_comment_text" name="content"></textarea>
                                                 <button class="add_comment_button" id="post_'.$post_id.'">Жіберу</button>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>';
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Перед циклом в котором будете выводить информацию объявите переменную:

   ```
   $index = 0;
   ```
2. Внутри цикла после вывода записи поставьте код

   ```
   $index++;
   if ($index % 10 == 0)
   {
     // тут выводите дополнительный div
   }
   ```

Comment: @KYRAN, цикла у меня в ответе нет! Он есть в вашем вопросе, про него и написано в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо вам я понял!